# How can I grant permission for a user over a direcotry in linux

Tags: linux

I use chmod to change the file permissions. But what if I needed to grant full control permission for the logged in user over a directory ?

Comment: you can chmod/chown/chgrp directories just as you can files

Comment: I typed: `chmod u+rwx mydir` and the command seems successful because the console does not give any errors. When I access the folder, I still find some files that does not have `x` permission for the current user. What is the reason ? Knowing that this folder is not created by me (the current user).

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: @JuryA: Ah, are you trying to _recursively_ apply the new permissions to _all_ child files/folders within the directory?  `chmod` has a `-R` flag for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did your try

`chmod u+rwx <your directory>`

from the directory above the directory you want to change? Be aware that a user can only change permissions of files/directories he owns.

If you want to change permissions of a directory and any subdirectories and files you have to use

`chmod -R u+rwx <your directory>`

Answer (score 0):

correcting my response :
**setfacl -m u:jvmohan:rwx directory-name**

This should set the acl on the directory for the specific user with name **jvmohan**

Comment: sry my mistake I think I made sandwith of chmod and chown ..let me correct my response to setfacl -m u:jvmohan:rwx d2

Comment: ofcourse with -R option you can set it recursively

Answer (score 0):

chmod works on files AND directories
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/unix-file-and-directory-permissions/